# about or-tools OnlyEnforceIf,AddBoolAnd question

Tags: or-tools

I have a Bool array, I want some ones to appear in certain places like this:
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] or [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],here I want four ones appear in array's head,or tail,just two places,how can I do this?

```py
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

shifts = {}
ones={}
sequence = []
for i in range(10):
        shifts[(i)] = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, "shifts(%i)" % i)
        ones[(i)] = model.NewBoolVar( '%i' % i)
        
for i in range(10):
    model.Add(shifts[(i)] ==8).OnlyEnforceIf(ones[(i)])
    model.Add(shifts[(i)] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(ones[(i)].Not()) 

#I want the four 8s in the array to only appear in two positions at the head or tail of the array, and not in other positions.
model.AddBoolAnd([ones[(0)],ones[(1)],ones[(2)],ones[(3)]])# appear in head
#model.AddBoolAnd([ones[(6)],ones[(7)],ones[(8)],ones[(9)]]) #appear in tauk ，error！

model.Add(sum(ones[(i)] for i in range(10)) == 4)
status = solver.Solve(model)
print("status:",status)

res=[]
for i in range(10):
        res.append(solver.Value(shifts[(i)]))
print(res)
```

**bold**
*italic*

> quote

Answer (score 3):

Try [AddAllowedAsignments](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddAllowedAssignments):

```py
model = cp_model.CpModel()
ones = [model.NewBoolVar("") for _ in range(10)]
model.AddAllowedAssignments(
    ones, [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
)
```

Edit: @Laurent's suggestion

```py
model = cp_model.CpModel()
ones = [model.NewBoolVar("") for _ in range(10)]
head = model.NewBoolVar("head")

# HEAD
model.AddImplication(head, ones[0])
model.AddImplication(head, ones[1])
model.AddImplication(head, ones[2])
model.AddImplication(head, ones[3])
model.AddImplication(head, ones[4].Not())
model.AddImplication(head, ones[5].Not())
...

# TAIL
model.AddImplication(head.Not(), ones[0].Not())
model.AddImplication(head.Not(), ones[1].Not())
....
model.AddImplication(head.Not(), ones[6])
model.AddImplication(head.Not(), ones[7])
model.AddImplication(head.Not(), ones[8])
model.AddImplication(head.Not(), ones[9])
```

Comment: hi,Stradivari, I'm looking for you ,could you tell me your contact information?

Comment: or in that case, one literal and a lot of implication. But I believe the expansion of the allowed assignment constraint will do just that.